# silverlight 4, getting html cookies

Tags: silverlight, cookies, silverlight-4.0

In Fiddler 2, Raw data shows the following cookies:

```
__utma_a2a=7477768302.1349257957.1317701031.1318843147.1318844585.14;   
 session="3YZAdX/xEuKVpYZWKBmcbC2S1YE=?
_flashes=KGxwMQooUydtZXNzYWdlJwpTJ0xvZ2dlZCBpbicKdHAyCmEoUydtZXNzYWdlJwpTJ0xvZ2dlZCBp
bicKdHAzCmEoUydtZXNzYWdlJwpTJ0xvZ2dlZCBpbicKdHA0CmEoUydtZXNzYWdlJwpTJ0xvZ2dlZCBpbicKd
HA1CmEoUydtZXNzYWdlJwpTJ0xvZ2dlZCBpbicKdHA2CmEoUydtZXNzYWdlJwpwNwpTJ0xvZ2dlZCBpbicKcD
gKdHA5CmEu&
_fresh=STAxCi4=&_id=UycwO0BAXHhlY1x4MTlceDA3LSBceGI1XHhlOVx4OWRceGQ3MFx4MTVceGIyJwpwMQou&
user_id=VjMKLg=="
```

(actually no space in between except after semicolon;)

But in Silverlight client

```
string[] cookies = System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.Cookies.Split(';');
```

gets only 1 entry to the semicolon. All starting 'session' isn't in there. How can I get whole cookie string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe the HTTP conversation again in Fiddler and take not of the earlier response that contains the `Set-Cookie` header that sets the `session` cookie in the first place.

I suspect that cookie will have the "httpOnly" directive which means that it can not be retrieved by client code, it will be excluded by the standard APIs that expose cookies to script (or in this case Silverlight) code.

Comment: Oh my, you are right. There's "HttpOnly" in Set-Cookie. Is there any way out if I use client http?