# silverlight login via html

Tags: silverlight, authentication

Is it possible to login via ordinary html page, and then load silverlight app? If so, 
how can I do that? My own approach was getting authentication cookie from silevrlight app's
hosting page:

```
string[] cookies = System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.Cookies.Split(';');
```

No luck so far.

Comment: "No luck" is not very good description of the problem you are having.  If you are not deliberately choosing to use the Silverlight ClientHTTP stack and authentication is actually stored in a cookie then you shouldn't need to do anything.

Comment: Sorry... I actually have a related question in SO. I use ClientHTTP. The related question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090917/silverlight-4-getting-html-cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can circumvent the HttpOnly nature of a session cookie by using some server-side code. (Of source you would need to assess whether this is something you really want do)

For example if the page hosting the Silverlight app is a .NET ASPX page then you can access the session ID with:-

```
if (Request.Cookies["session"] != null)
{
    initParams.Attributes["session"] = Request.Cookies["session"].Value
}
```

Where the Silverlight `<object>` element has the following child:-

```
     <param name="initParams" id="initParams" runat="server" />
```

Now inside sliverlight you can access this value and add it in a `CookieContainer` which you use with all your ClientHttp requests.

Answer (score 1):

Direct answer is yes it is possible. As Anthony W Jones stated in a comment, if you use browser http stack, and session cookie is set, then nothing else is required. If you want to use client http then see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could host your Silverlight application on a web page that requires authentication. This way, only authorized visitors will run it.

Or could you elaborate your question? I'm not sure if I understand well what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: All authentication examples I saw did it within silevrlight application, after the xap files were loaded. What I want to do is authenticate via ordinary html form, and only then load silverlight app.